# Extracting specific data from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a large text from which I want to extract data according to a specific scheme.

Scheme:

> (something) something (something|something)

for example

> (Point A) 147 (-10|22) or
>   (City) 479 (147|-20)

There are many such phrases in my text and I would like to write each one to array.

Comment: please add your try. what does not work?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This regexp should do the trick for you:

```js
const input = 'Some other text (City) 479 (147|-20) Some other text';

const result = /\(\s*([^)]*)\s*\)\s*([^(]*)\s*\(\s*([^|]*)\s*\|\s*([^)]*)\s*\)/g.exec(input);

console.log(result);
```